# Rotating background color in ReactJS

Tags: reactjs

I have this code in my JS folder...

```
var bgColors = { 
  "Default": "#81b71a",
  "Blue": "#00B1E1",
  "Cyan": "#37BC9B",
  "Green": "#8CC152",
  "Red": "#E9573F",
  "Yellow": "#F6BB42"
};


class App extends Component {      
  constructor() {        
    super();

    this.state = {
      name: 'React'
    };
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
       <Helmet>
         <style>{'body { background-color: red; }'}</style>
       </Helmet>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

As you can see. the background is set to red. How do I make the background color rotate colors every second or so? I want the colors to rotate through the list of colors I established.

Comment: You're asking us to do your job... When you think about intervals in JS, what's the first function that comes to your mind? Do you know how to set state in React? For those questions, there are tons of answers right here at SO.

Comment: Please direct me in the right direstion. I am new to React.

Comment: I did it already... ;) 1) how to set Intervals in JS?, 2) how to set state in React? Combine the answers and voilà!

Answer (score 1):

```js
var bgColors = { 
  default: "#81b71a",
  blue: "#00B1E1",
  cyan: "#37BC9B",
  green: "#8CC152",
  red: "#E9573F",
  yellow: "#F6BB42",
};

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      bgColor: bgColors.default,
    };
    
    this.interval = setInterval(() => {
      let randomColor = bgColors[
        Object.keys(bgColors)[
          Math.floor(Math.random() *
          Object.keys(bgColors).length)
        ]
      ];
      this.setState(() => ({bgColor: randomColor}))
    }, 1000);
  }
  
  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.interval)
  }
  
  render() {
    return (
      <div 
        style={{
          height: '200px',
          backgroundColor: this.state.bgColor
        }}
      >
        Background color changes every second
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id="root"></div>
```